# Manhwa about a girl reborn but dying because of her drawing and painting ability

Tags: story-identification, manga

I trying to find this manhwa/manga. It's about a girl who dies because of her ability. She comes back a few years before she dies and leaves her family. She runs off to her fiancé and plans to live with him until she dies again because of her ability.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was this in colour or black-and-white? What was her name? What did she look like? Why was her ability killing her? Was there any sex/nudity/gore? What was the name of the love interest? Do other people have abilities? Are these abilities genetic or magic? Are there other examples of magic in this universe? What is the setting?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like [Karina's last days](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/karinas-last-days). Synopsis from Tapas:

> Though gifted with an ability to bring her drawings to life, Karina Leopold spent her years in the shadow of her famous siblings, forced to be the good daughter her parents wanted. But when she’s told that a deadly disease will kill her in a year, she offers a deal to her fiancé, Milian Pastellio, with the goal to live the remainder of her days far from her family’s reach. Much to her surprise, their encounter proceeds to change them both in a way she never imagined…

The synopsis pretty much covers everything, except for the regression part. I can not remember that happening, and a brief revisit of the first to chapters shows no regression.